# Visual Studio - General Purpose Handler

Tags: vb.net, event-handling, visual-studio-2013, menuitem

I have a few menu items in my project that open new forms when clicked and every time I click on one I run the code below. However I have to add it for each `MenuItem_Click` event, so whenever I change the code I have to copy and past between forms. `FormName` is the only thing that changes. All of my menu items are named after the corresponding form, `mi_FormName`. And I know how to make a general event handler.

Is there any way to make it grab the name of the clicked on menu item, remove the `mi_`, and insert it in the same places as `FormName`?

```
   Private Sub MenuItem_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MenuItem.Click

    Dim F As Form
    If Not IsNothing(modForms.CheckOpen("FormName")) Then
        F = modForms.CheckOpen("FormName")
        If F.IsDisposed Then
            modForms.CheckOpen.Remove("FormName")
            F = New FormName
            F.Show()
        ElseIf F.Visible = False Then
            F.Show()
        Else
            F.BringToFront()
        End If
    Else
        F = New FormName
        F.Show()
    End If

End Sub
```

Comment: you can write a sub or function for that code and pass the form name as a param.  then just call it from the various places (resolve the NON GENERIC aspects in the click events then invoke the common code).  you might want to pass the type (form) you wish to create unless it is always the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use a lambda that passes along the type of the form?  You can use `GetType` to find the textual name and use a simple constraint to allow instances to be created

```
AddHandler mi_FormName.Click, Sub(s, e) OnClick(Of FormName)
AddHandler mi_OtherForm.Click, Sub(s, e) OnClick(Of OtherForm)
```

The click handler would look essentially as follows

```
Private Sub OnClick(Of T As {New, Form})()
    Dim name = GetType(T).Name
    Dim F As Form
    If Not IsNothing(modForms.CheckOpen(name)) Then
        F = modForms.CheckOpen(name)
        If F.IsDisposed Then
            modForms.CheckOpen.Remove(name)
            F = New T
            F.Show()
        ElseIf F.Visible = False Then
            F.Show()
        Else
            F.BringToFront()
        End If
    Else
        F = New T
        F.Show()
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank You! But I don't know what this error means `Lambda parameter 'e' hides a variable in an enclosing block, a previously defined range variable, or an implicitly declared variable in a query expression.`

Comment: @IanO just change `e` to another name which doesn't conflict